# Android Air Native Extension to install new apk version throws "no activity found to handle intent"

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, air, air-native-extension

All I want is to install (ask user for) new application version stored on sdcard as .apk file using Adobe Air Native Extension.

Here is my ANE function code:

```
@Override
//args[0] is the path to local stored apk (logs as /storage/sdcard0/testStorage/updates/1.1apk)
public FREObject call(FREContext _context, FREObject[] args) {
     context = _context;

     try {             
         Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(args[0].getAsString()), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
         promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.getActivity().startActivity(promptInstall);

         alert("Okay", "start was!"); //using AlertDialog for debug purpose

     } catch (Exception e) {
             alert("Error!", e.getLocalizedMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
     } 

 return null;
}
```

And here is manifest I'm using:

```
 <android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
    <application android:debuggable="true"/>
    <application>
        <activity android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" />
</manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
  </android>
```

But I'm always getting "No activity found to handle Intent error":

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/sdcard0/testStorage/updates/1.1.apk typ=application/vnd.adnroid.package-archive flg=0x10000000}

**Added**

```
File setupFile = new File(args[0].getAsString());
alert("Is exists?", Boolean.toString(setupFile .exists())); //output as true
```

Said that file is real and args[0] path is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of google i found that the problem was in missing "file://"

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + args[0].getAsString()), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

Now everything work fine!

Comment: Please make sure you mark your own answer as correct when you are able to (generally 2 days after the question was posted)